# How to create the link between Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE?

Tags: windows, fortran, fortran90

I install both software  Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE but when I open the Visual Studio 2017, it only shows the Visual C++ and C#. It can't show the Visual Fortran. Both software are install in Windows 10.

Comment: Have you followed the VS2017 guide here? https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2017-for-use-with-intel-compilers

Comment: @GlennWatson Yes try it but still not working

Comment: See https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/troubleshooting-fortran-integration-issues-with-visual-studio/  If that doesn't help, ask in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: @SteveLionel rc.exe not found. Now what can i do now

Comment: Usually what I suggest is to uninstall both the Intel and Microsoft products, delete the Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio folder, then reinstall Visual Studio (making sure C++ is selected) and then Intel Parallel Studio. If that doesn't help, then please ask in the Intel forum (link above) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently the installer doesn't install the Visual Studio integration properly.

1. First, you must have the proper certificates installed, as described in [this article in the Intel Fortran forums](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-tools-integration-to-vs2017-issue#issue8).  It appears that the "COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA" certificate may no longer be needed, but the other two are still required.
2. The Visual Studio integration is installed by a number of .vsix files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools`.  If the installer fails, you can install these files manually.
3. Use the Visual Studio IDE to remove all Intel extensions.  (Main Menu -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates ... in VS 2017; Main Menu -> Extensions in VS 2019)
4. If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, BEWARE.  The *.vsix extensions may offer to install themselves for versions of Visual Studio which they are not designed to handle.  The ones designed for VS 2017 will have v15 in their name or may be filed under a VS 15 folder; the ones for VS 2019 will have v16 in their name or be files under a VS 16 folder.
5. To install a .vsix file, just double click on it in Microsoft File Explorer.
6. Re-install the extensions (.vsix files) in the following order: Common Tools, C++ (if any; use alphabetical order if there are more than one), Intel Software Manager, FEE, Advisor (if present), Inspector (if present), VTune (if present).  Repeat the installation of the .vsix files for each version of Visual Studio that you have.
7. If you update Visual C++ or Visual Fortran, you will need to repeat steps 3-5 at least.  (You might have to uninstall and reinstall both compilers, but I am hoping that will not be necessary.)